# Joining array lists of set in Java

Tags: java

I have two lists of sets. I want to join them as below. Will sorting both the lists and then joining the sets for each index of lists be an efficient method?

```
    List A  
    =======  
    {a, 2, 3}  
    {b, 17, 6}  
    {c, -1, 5}  
    List B  
    =======  
    {b, "Tommy", "Hill"}  
    {a, "W", "-1"}  
    {c, "l", "O"}  
    Output  
    ======  
    {a, 2, 3, "W", "-1"}  
    {b, 17, 6, "Tommy", "Hill"}  
    {c, -1, 5, "l", "O"}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Made this post! That gotta count? Right? Right!? (Jokes aside), the result you want is very clear. But generally no one here is supposed to write the code for you, but help you on the way / get started. If getting started is a problem (it can be) it can be hard to formulate the problem domain, then simply ask for that. "I want to do X with A I don't know how to get started..." and pointers will be given, once you have a foundation you can get back and ask another question more directed at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create Lists

```
List <String> A1=Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a","2","3"});
List <String> A2= // complete it
List <String> A3= // complete it

List <String> B1=Arrays.asList(new String[] {"b","Tommy","Hill"});
List <String> B2= // complete it
List <String> B3= // complete it
```

Insert them in a Set< List>

```
Set<List<String>> A=new HashSet<List<String>>(); A.add(A1); A.add(A2); A.add(A3);
Set<List<String>> B=new HashSet<List<String>>(); B.add(B1); B.add(B2); B.add(B3);
```

Iterate on you sets

```
for (List <String>  Ax: A)
    {
    String the_index=Ax.get(0);

    for (List <String>  Bx: B)
```

search on first item

```
        if (the_index.equals(Bx.get(0)))
                // Join
                {
                List <String> result=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Take first list

```
                result.addAll(Ax);
```

add continuation in second list

```
                result.addAll(Bx.subList(1, Bx.size()));
                System.out.println(result);
                }
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

You should use `set.retainAll()` to find intersection of two sets. if intersection exists, you can use JAVA 8 stream feature to concat two sets:

```
Set<String> combinedSet = Stream.concat(Set1.stream(), set2.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Is it possible in Java 7?

Comment: Stream in new addition in JAVA8 i dont think it can be used in java7